# java DES encrypt code convert to ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, des

Hi I have a java android encrypt method, and want to convert to ruby code.

```
IvParameterSpec localIvParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[] { 12, 34, 34, 11, 64, 23, 89, 27 });

DESKeySpec localDESKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(paramString2.getBytes());

SecretKey localSecretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(localDESKeySpec);

Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

localCipher.init(1, localSecretKey, localIvParameterSpec);

return new String(Base64.encode(localCipher.doFinal(paramString1.getBytes()), 0));
```

and I google some useful articles, but still could not get the same output.
So anyone know the ruby code as above java code?

Thx!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Stefan 
Errr... Sorry. My question is what is the ruby code as java code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("DES-CBC")
des.encrypt
des.key = "xxxx"
des.iv = "xxxx"
cipher = des.update(str) + des.final
Base64.strict_encode64(cipher)
```